# Official API or way to get the current separator setting (e.g., `,` or `;`) of Excel formulas

Tags: ms-office, office-js

As there are already more than 1000 Office JavaScript APIs, I would like to know if there is an official API or way to get the current separator setting (e.g., `,` or `;`) of Excel formulas.

Determining it from a formula is not always possible, for example, in a workbook without any formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Office JS Excel API currently doesn't have API to get separator for the formulas based on the locale. therefore, I would suggest that you could submit the request and upvote this request at [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563)

But to unblock your scenario, you could consider a workaround, detect the locale using `cultureInfor.name` from [cultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.cultureinfo?view=excel-js-preview) and figure out separator accordingly.

Here is the sample code for your reference:

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    var app = context.workbook.application;
    var ci = app.cultureInfo;
    ci.load("name");
    await context.sync();
    var seperator;
    if (ci.name = "en-US")
      seperator = ","
    else if (ci.name = "de-DE")
      seperator = ";"
    // continue determine the separator by other locale

    console.log("Culture: " + ci.name + " and Seperator: " + seperator);
  });
```

Comment: How did you know the separator of `en-US` if `,`, and the separator of `de-DE` is `;`? Do you have a match table?